# Android : how to chose between background Thread with looper and Service

Tags: android

by my understand about looper that it's can be a central for running by any request pass through
handler in message and Service can do that too. So what is adventage of each(priority of thread,reliable,resource,...) to decided to use.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with `Handler` i would say is basic approach, create `Thread` and implement `Handler` but if you work on more complex application, you should decide rather for `AsyncTask`, that is more complex, type safer, faster and offers more options. You can declare it like inner class or also separated class.

`Services` is more complicated, you should know that only one `Service` can be in memory at the time, only one instance, one copy of Service and also when more `Activities` are trying to connection to `Service`. Services are generally used when you have very long `Tasks` and you want to they keep running also when they are not connected with any `Activity` for example Music player, RSS, keep status on Chat etc. But this all not free so you have to care about CPU to prevent prematurely battery exhaustion for example.

If i recommend to you so first try to use `AsyncTask` and when for something it's won't suitable for you or you need something what i wrote above, get it with `Service`.

More about [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and have look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)